# Alternatives for a many-to-many link table

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many

I am working on a project where I want to allow the end user to basically add an unlimited amount of resources when creating a hardware device listing.

In this scenario, they can store both the quantity and types of hard-drives. The hard-drive types are already stored in a MySQL Database table with all of the potential options, so they have the options to set quantity, choose the drive type (from dropdown box), and add more entries as needed.

As I don't want to create a DB with "drive1amount", "drive1typeid", "drive2amount", "drive2typeid", and so on, what would be the best way to do this?

I've seen similar questions answered with a many-to-many link table, but can't think of how I could pull this off with that.

Comment: if there is 10 extra content need to add, just alter the table and add 10 extra column, or create a new table and  one-to-one relationship with the base table, no need for creating to much DB or tables, friend with columns :D

Comment: @user2511414 the wider your tables get the problems you will start having as your rows increase.

Comment: @DevZer0 isn't better than having 1000 DB or table? there to many architecture available for preventing query performances, why don't you split the table?

Comment: 1000 tables designed well doesn't cause any issue. Its all about how you normalize your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE `hardware` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hardware_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `type_id` (`hardware_type_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `hardware_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hardware_type_id`) REFERENCES `hardware_type` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

hardware_type_id  is a foreign key to your existing table

This way the table doesnt care what kind of hardware it is

Comment: I admit I am not the best with any advanced MySQL and have never used constraint/foreign_key/references before. However, it looks like that is essentially about the same as doing "disk1_type_id", "disk2_type_id", etc. except essentially casting it to a specific table?

Comment: Not quite, this scales a lot better, what if you wanted a third disk or fouth, or 10th? YOu now have a lot of columns for no reason, this setup you only have "one extra" column If you want to add more types all you do is add another row in your foreign table (which is normal). Look into database normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization  specifically first normal form

Answer (score 0):

Your answer relies a bit on your long term goals with this project. If you want to posses a data repository which has profiles all different types of hardware devices with their specifications i suggest you maintain a hardware table of each different types of hardware. For example you will have a harddisk table which consist of all different models and types of hardisks out there. Then you can assign a record from this specific table to the host configuration table. You can build the dataset as you go from the input from user.

If this is not clear to you let me know i will create a diagram and upload for you.

Comment: My project needs aren't necessarily that in depth. I could even just give the user text fields if I wasn't anal about having the names all appear in a given way. I could probably get away with just doing 5-10 columns in the master "device" table, but as I need to do this for drives, ram, etc. I felt that there may be a better way.

Comment: To follow up, I actually do already have tables with the various device listings. A CPU table lists all of the potential processors, drives lists all of the specific drives, etc. The problem is I need to allow them to potentially select multiple and set a quantity of how many of each there are and keep that recorded. This is actually the second project where this has been an issue so I really need to get it figured out :)

Comment: @BrettPowell so you mean want to have something like card? presenting a pc system?

Comment: As I think about it more, I guess the best way to do it is have 3 tables. Table A) One for each "machine", Table B) one that keeps all hard-drives assigned to machines, and then C) one that stores the types of drives. Then in B store the ID of A, if that makes sense? Thats the best I can come up with.